# Let $H<G$. Assume $G\setminus H=H/G$. Show that for every $g\in G$ there exists $g'\in G$ s.t. $g\cdot H=H\cdot g'$

Tags: group-theory

I have the following Problem:

> Let $G$ be a group and $H<G$ be a subgroup. We assume that $G\setminus H=H/G$, i.e. every left-$H$ coset is also a right-$H$ coset and vice versa. Show that for every $g\in G$ there exists $g'\in G$ s.t. $g\cdot H=H\cdot g'$

I want to show this in the following way:

Let $g\in G$. Then by assumption  $G\setminus H=H\,/\,G \Leftrightarrow \{gH\mid g\in G\}=\{Hg\mid g\in G\}$. But now I can chose $g'=g$ and then it follows immediately that $g\cdot H=H\cdot g'$.

But I'm not sure if this works since it was really immediate.

Comment: Isn't the claim precisely the assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $gH$ be a left coset for arbitrary $g\in G$. This can be done because cosets partition $G$. Since, by hypothesis, $gH$ is also a right coset, there exists a $g'\in G$ such that $gH=Hg'$, which is precisely what we need to prove.

Comment: but can't we say that we chose $g=g'$? So do my prove work?

Comment: No, @Strandkorb. That only works for normal subgroups.

Comment: Sorry if I ask here again, but I showed that $1\in H(g'g^{-1}$. Now I need to deduce from this that H is normal. But I somehow don't see why this follows from the fact above. So $1\in H(g'g^{-1})\Rightarrow 1=hg'g^{-1}\Leftrightarrow g=hg'$ If h=1 then it would follow immediately but I don't think that h=1. Therefore could you gave me a hint, not the whole solution. Thank you

Comment: That's a separate question, @Strandkorb; I suggest you post is separately. If you understood my solution to your original question, please accept it.

Comment: Done, maybe you can look at it

Comment: I'm afraid I'm at work for the next several hours, @Strandkorb. Good luck with it though.